# PowerShell: Intersection of more than two arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, set-intersection

Using PowerShell, I have 14 arrays of strings. Some of the arrays are empty. How would I get the intersection (all elements that exist in all of the arrays) of these arrays (excluding the arrays that are empty)? I am trying to avoid comparing two arrays at a time.

Some of the arrays are empty, so I do not want to include those in my comparisons. Any ideas on how I would approach this? Thank you.

```
$a = @('hjiejnfnfsd','test','huiwe','test2')
$b = @('test','jnfijweofnew','test2')
$c = @('njwifqbfiwej','test','jnfijweofnew','test2')
$d = @('bhfeukefwgu','test','dasdwdv','test2','hfuweihfei')
$e = @('test','ddwadfedgnh','test2')
$f = @('test','test2')
$g = @('test','bjiewbnefw','test2')
$h = @('uie287278hfjf','test','huiwhiwe','test2')
$i = @()
$j = @()
$k = @('jireohngi','test','gu7y8732hbj','test2')
$l = @()
$m = @('test','test2')
$n = @('test','test2')
```

My attempt to solve this (although it does not check for empty arrays):

```
$overlap = Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $c -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $d -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $e -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $f -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $g -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $h -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $i -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $j -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $k -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $l -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $m -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
$overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $n -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
```

My desired result is that test and test2 appear in $overlap. This solution does not work because it does not check if the array it is comparing is empty.

Comment: "In this case, we should see test and test2 in $overlap." — And do you?  What is the result of and problem with the posted code?  Also, in the array definitions are the elements strings or variable names?  That won't execute as-posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The following assumes that no individual array contains the same string more than once (more work would be needed to address that).

```bash
$a = @('hjiejnfnfsd','test','huiwe','test2')
$b = @('test','jnfijweofnew','test2')
$c = @('njwifqbfiwej','test','jnfijweofnew','test2')
$d = @('bhfeukefwgu','test','dasdwdv','test2','hfuweihfei')
$e = @('test','ddwadfedgnh','test2')
$f = @('test','test2')
$g = @('test','bjiewbnefw','test2')
$h = @('uie287278hfjf','test','huiwhiwe','test2')
$i = @()
$j = @()
$k = @('jireohngi','test','gu7y8732hbj','test2')
$l = @()
$m = @('test','test2')
$n = @('test','test2')

$allArrays = $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k, $l, $m, $n

# Initialize a hashtable in which we'll keep
# track of unique strings and how often they occur.
$ht = @{}

# Loop over all arrays.
$nonEmptyArrayCount = 0
foreach ($arr in $allArrays) {
  # Loop over each non-empty array's elements.
  if ($arr.Count -gt 0) {
    ++$nonEmptyArrayCount 
    foreach ($el in $arr) {
      # Add each string and increment its occurrence count.
      $ht[$el] += 1
    }
  }
}

# Output all strings that occurred in every non-empty array
$ht.GetEnumerator() |
  Where-Object Value -eq $nonEmptyArrayCount |
  ForEach-Object Key
```

The above outputs those strings that are present in *all* of the *non-empty* input arrays:

```
test2
test
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using a [`Hashset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0). A `Hashset` is a collection that stores only *unique* items and provides *fast lookup*, which makes it a good choice for intersection calculation. It even has a method [`IntersectWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=net-6.0) which accepts any *enumerable* type (such as an array) as argument. The method modifies the original `Hashset` so that it contains only the elements which are contained in both the `Hashset` and the argument passed to the method.

```sh
# Test input
$a = @()     # I changed this to empty array for demonstration purposes
$b = @('test','jnfijweofnew','test2')
$c = @('njwifqbfiwej','test','jnfijweofnew','test2')
$d = @('bhfeukefwgu','test','dasdwdv','test2','hfuweihfei')
$e = @('test','ddwadfedgnh','test2')
$f = @('test','test2')
$g = @('test','bjiewbnefw','test2')
$h = @('uie287278hfjf','test','huiwhiwe','test2')
$i = @()
$j = @()
$k = @('jireohngi','test','gu7y8732hbj','test2')
$l = @()
$m = @('test','test2')
$n = @('test','test2')

# Create a variable with a type-constraint
[Collections.Generic.Hashset[object]] $overlap = $null

# For each of the arrays...
($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k, $l, $m, $n).
    Where{ $_.Count -gt 0 }.           #... except the empty ones
    ForEach{
        # If the Hashset has not been initialized yet
        if( $null -eq $overlap ) {
            # Create the initial hashset from the first non-empty array.
            $overlap = $_
        }
        else { 
            # Hashset is already initialized, calculate the intersection with next non-empty array.
            $overlap.IntersectWith( $_ )
        }
    }

$overlap  # Output
```

**Output:**

```text
test
test2
```

**Remarks:**

- To filter out empty arrays (or in general any kind of *collection*), we check its `Count` member, which gives the number of elements.
- `.Foreach` and `.Where` are PowerShell [intrinsic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#methods-of-arrays). These can be faster than the `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` commands, especially when working directly with collections (as opposed to output of another command). The automatic variable `$_` represents the current element of the collection, as usual.

  This code using pipeline commands is functionally the same:

  ```sh
  [Collections.Generic.Hashset[object]] $overlap = $null

  $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k, $l, $m, $n |
      Where-Object Count -gt 0 |           
      ForEach-Object{
          if( $null -eq $overlap ) {  
              $overlap = $_ 
          }
          else { 
              $overlap.IntersectWith( $_ )   
          }
      }
  ```
- In `if( $null -eq $overlap )` it is very important that `$null` is on the left-hand-side of the `-eq` operator. If it were on the right-hand-side, PowerShell would do an element-wise comparison with `$null` to *filter* elements instead of checking if the variable `$overlap` itself is `$null` (see [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2))
- In the line `$overlap = $_` PowerShell automatically converts the current array into a `Hashset`, because we have set a *type constraint* using `[Collections.Generic.Hashset[object]] $overlap` before and `array` is convertible to `Hashset` (see [About Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2#types-of-variables)).
- String comparison of a `Hashset` is *case-sensitive* by default. To make it *case-insensitive*, convert each string to lowercase like this:

  ```sh
  [Collections.Generic.Hashset[object]] $overlap = $null

  ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k, $l, $m, $n).
      Where{ $_.Count -gt 0 }.
      ForEach{
          if( $null -eq $overlap ) {
              $overlap = $_.ToLower()
          }
          else { 
              $overlap.IntersectWith( $_.ToLower() )
          }
      }
  ```

  This uses [member access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) to call the `String.ToLower()` method for each element of the input arrays.
- With the first variant, inserting a linebreak *before* `Where` and `ForEach` is not really necessary, but improves code readability (note that you can't insert a linebreak *before* `.Where` and `.ForEach`, because this confuses the PowerShell parser).

Comment: There is a pitfall where I believe that if the `$Overlap` gets empty during the process the intersecting restarts from the beginning (test e.g. with: `$m = 'x'; $n = 'y'` the overlap should be empty but is `'y'`). In other words, it is better to start with `$overlap = $Null` and check `if( $Null -eq $overlap) { ...` (rather than `$overlap.Count -eq 0`)

Comment: @iRon Nice find! I've fixed the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  Excluding empty arrays from comparison is **essential** because the intersection of an empty array and any other array is an empty array, and once `$overlap` contains an empty array that will be the final result regardless of what subsequent arrays contain.

Here's your code with the non-empty check and rewritten using loops...

```powershell
$a = @('hjiejnfnfsd', 'test', 'huiwe', 'test2')
$b = @('test', 'jnfijweofnew', 'test2')
$c = @('njwifqbfiwej', 'test', 'jnfijweofnew', 'test2')
$d = @('bhfeukefwgu', 'test', 'dasdwdv', 'test2', 'hfuweihfei')
$e = @('test', 'ddwadfedgnh', 'test2')
$f = @('test', 'test2')
$g = @('test', 'bjiewbnefw', 'test2')
$h = @('uie287278hfjf', 'test', 'huiwhiwe', 'test2')
$i = @()
$j = @()
$k = @('jireohngi', 'test', 'gu7y8732hbj', 'test2')
$l = @()
$m = @('test', 'test2')
$n = @('test', 'test2')

# Create an array of arrays $a through $n
$arrays = @(
    # 'a'..'n' doesn't work in Windows PowerShell
    # Define both ends of the range...
    #             'a'    → [String]
    #             'a'[0] → [Char]
    #     [Int32] 'a'[0] → 97 (ASCII a)
    # ...and cast each element back to a [Char]
    [Char[]] ([Int32] 'a'[0]..[Int32] 'n'[0]) |
        Get-Variable -ValueOnly
)

# Initialize $overlap to the first non-empty array
for ($initialOverlapIndex = 0; $initialOverlapIndex -lt $arrays.Length; $initialOverlapIndex++)
{
    if ($arrays[$initialOverlapIndex].Length -gt 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
<#
    Alternative:
        $initialOverlapIndex = [Array]::FindIndex(
            $arrays,
            [Predicate[Array]] { param($array) $array.Length -gt 0 }
        )
#>
$overlap = $arrays[$initialOverlapIndex]

for ($comparisonIndex = $initialOverlapIndex + 1; $comparisonIndex -lt $arrays.Length; $comparisonIndex++)
# Alternative: foreach ($array in $arrays | Select-Object -Skip $initialOverlapIndex)
{
    $array = $arrays[$comparisonIndex]
    if ($array.Length -gt 0)
    {
        $overlap = Compare-Object $overlap $array -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
    }
}

$overlap
```

...which outputs...

```
test
test2
```